# extJS: How to register events in a dynamically created grid.Panel in MVC?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am trying to open a form when I double click on a dynamically created Grid. This is not a problem for the static grids, however when I create dynamic ones, I am unable to catch the double click event.

My Navigation Controller (the one that creates the Panels and adds them) looks like this:

```
//Housekeeping and helper functions removed
onNavigationSelection: function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {
    var groupsstore = this.getGroupsStore();

    groupsstore.load({
        callback: this.createPanels,
        params: {},
        scope:this
    });
},
createPanels: function() {
for (var i = 0; i < groupArrayCounter.length; i++) {
        var storeName = 'store' + groupArrayCounter[i];
        var panelName = 'panel' + groupArrayCounter[i];
        var newstore = createStore(storeName, GroupArrays[groupArrayCounter[i]]);
        var panel = createPanel(panelName, newstore);
        this.getGroupPanel().add(panel);
}

    function createStore(name, data) {
        var createstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
            requires: 'NG.model.Person',
            model: 'NG.model.Person',
            data: data,
            fields: ['id', 'auc', 'dateAdmitted', 'name', 'cpr', 'department', 'group' , 'active', 'dateBooked', 'dateStart', 'dateEndCalculated', 'dateEndActual', 'comments']
        });

        return createstore;
}

    function createPanel(name, store) {
        var createpanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            title: " Muh ",
            alias: 'widget.'+name,
            columns: [
                {header: 'Navn', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1}
            ]});

        return createpanel;
}
```

My ChangePerson Controller (the one where you should be able to double click a person):

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'activepersons': {
            itemdblclick: this.onActivepersonsClick
        },
        'waitingpersons': {
            itemdblclick: this.onWaitingpersonsClick
        },
        'group': {
            itemdblclick: this.onGroupClick
        },
        //This is what I want, but it does not work
        'panel17': {
            itemdblclick: this.onGroupClick
        },
        //This is what I want, but it does not work
        'panel19': {
            itemdblclick: this.onGroupClick
        }

    });
},
onActivePersonsClick: function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {
    var view = Ext.widget('personform');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},
onWaitingPersonsClick: function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {
    var view = Ext.widget('personform');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},
// Is never called
onGroupClick: function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {
    var view = Ext.widget('personform');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
}
```

From debugging I know that there is a grid.Panel with the alias panel17 and panel19 created, BUT since they are added later, the above does of course not work. What I want to accomplish is to hook up the onGroupClick event in my ChangePerson controller to my dynamically created grid, but I have no idea on how to do this, since I don't seem to be able to access the ChangePerson Controller in my Navigation Controller.

Best regards and thank you advance!

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.control adds listener to the classes existing when the controller is created.
A simple solution is to use the function `on` to attach an event after the panel was created, something like:

```
 function createPanel(name, store) {
        var createpanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            title: " Muh ",
            alias: 'widget.'+name,
            columns: [
                {header: 'Navn', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1}
            ]});
        createdPanel.on('itemdblclick', function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {
                      var view = Ext.widget('personform');
                      view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
                   });
        return createpanel;
}
```

Comment: Hi nscrop!

Thank you for your reply!

I was not able to add the listener there (as I got a object function has no method 'on') error, BUT I could create it on the function initiating the call so I added your code (`createdPanel.on`) after `var panel = createPanel(panelName, newstore);` and it worked perfectly :) Thank you very much!